# using one useMemo value to another useMemo filter list and select one when pressing enter

Tags: reactjs, react-usememo

i want to filter countries name and set the first value as input value but when i select or set the input value to the first country the results get disappear until the input value is reset to empty. can you help me with the right approch if using the useEffect is better or should i use the useMemo still. thanks.

```
 import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";
    import { Users } from "../../fakeData/users";
    const Test6 = () => {
      const [countries, setCountries] = useState([
        { name: "Pakistan" },
        { name: "India" },
        { name: "Germany" },
        { name: "England" },
      ]);
    
      const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
      const [showSuggestionBox, setShowSuggestionBox] = useState(false);
      const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);
      const filteredCountries = useMemo(() => {
        if (!search) return countries;
        console.log(search);
        return countries.filter((country) =>
          country.name.toLowerCase().includes(search)
        );
      }, [search, countries]);
      const selectedCountry = useMemo(() => {
        if (!search.length || !isFocused) return;
        if (!filteredCountries?.length) return;
    
        return filteredCountries[0];
      }, [filteredCountries, search, isFocused]);
      return (
        <div>
          <div>
            <input
              onKeyUp={(e) => {
                if (e.key === "Enter") {
                  setSearch(selectedCountry?.name);
                }
              }}
              type="text"
              onBlur={() => {
                setIsFocused(false);
              }}
              onFocus={() => {
                setIsFocused(true);
              }}
              value={search}
              placeholder="Search Country"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setSearch(e.target.value);
              }}
            />
            {isFocused || search.length ? (
              <div className="">
                {filteredCountries.map((country) => {
                  return (
                    <div
                      key={country.name}
                      className={`${
                        search.length ? "first:bg-blue-500 first:text-white" : ""
                      }`}>
                      {country.name}
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            ) : (
              ""
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Test6;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working now

i was set the search to a value with upper case i converted it to lower case and it is working now.

```
 setSearch(filteredCountries[0].name.toLowerCase());
```